# verfiy password for a PKCS#12 file

Tags: encryption, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

In my php program I try to verify the password for a **PKCS#12** file (.p12/.pfx) with this **OpenSSL** command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in myDigitalID.p12 -noout -passin pass:mypassword
```

output:

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Error outputting keys and certificates
C4500000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work! please can any one help?
thanks

Comment: What version(s) of OpenSSL were involved in generating the .p12 file, and verification?  What OS platform(s) are involved?

Comment: I don't know much about how it was generated, because i got it from my university (each student can get a digital ID). For the verification I use OpenSSL 3.0.1 on Windows 10. But I guess it was generated with a different version of OpenSSL, could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes, differing versions, platforms, and CSPs might make a difference.  I might try importing it into a certificate store, just to see if it works, and if any additional error information might be revealed.

Answer (score 8):

If the command used to work in previous OpenSSL version try the following

Failing command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in myDigitalID.p12 -noout -passin pass:mypassword
```

Failing command output:

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2000
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2000
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2000
Error outputting keys and certificates
0C670000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

Ensure you have the legacy library (file named legacy*., e.g. legacy-x64.dll). Instead of configuring environment variables it may be easier to just copy the library as legacy. (e.g. legacy.dll) in both the libraries path and the path containing openssl executable.

Then try command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in myDigitalID.p12 -noout -passin pass:mypassword -legacy -provider-path "C:\path\to\legacy_dir" -provider default
```

This time it should work and show something like this:

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2000
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2000
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2000
Certificate bag
```

Comment: See similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859711/convert-an-old-style-p12-to-pem-unsupported-algorithm-rc2-40-cbc

Comment: openssl help says : "-legacy             Use legacy encryption: 3DES_CBC for keys, RC2_CBC for certs"