# Convert an old style .p12 to .pem (unsupported algorithm RC2-40-CBC)

Tags: openssl, keytool, pkcs#12

There seem to exist still some tools which generate private keys encrypted with RC2-40-CBC

Although I'm able to export it to a new key store using `keytool -importkeystore` it seems that I can't get rid of this algorithm.

How to convert them to PEM ?

OpenSSL fails with:

```
digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

Answer (score 81):

`openssl` has a key algorithm provider called `legacy`. Just try with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.p12 -legacy -nodes
```

Comment: this produces invalid key

Comment: This is a working solution. From a valid PKCS#12 file it will produce an intact key.

Answer (score 6):

You can change it permamently in OpenSSL configuration. Just modify file `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Find the `[default_sect]` section and change it to:

```
[default_sect]
activate = 1
[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Then find the `[provider_sect]` and use:

```
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect
```

Save file.