# Error extracting a Cert & Key from a .p12 file

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to extract cert & key from a .p12 file. Running this command in OpenSLL

openssl pkcs12 -info -in certificate.p12 -nodes

It prompts for a password, but after that I get this error:

Error outputting keys and certificates
1C400000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()

Does it sound like an issue with the OpenSSL version? I have version 3.0.7 installed on my Windows computer.

Thank you!

Comment: Does `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859711/convert-an-old-style-p12-to-pem-unsupported-algorithm-rc2-40-cbc` work?

Comment: It did not. This is what I get:

pkcs12: unable to load provider legacy
Hint: use -provider-path option or OPENSSL_MODULES environment variable.

Comment: I'm guessing then you may be on v3 and you may have to install v1.

Comment: [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72859712/1961303) helped me. Shortly speaking: add `-legacy` option.

Comment: The OpenSSL pkcs12 command with the -legacy option generates a PKCS#12 file using "legacy" encryption algorithms, such as RC2 and MD5. These encryption algorithms are considered insecure by modern cryptographic standards.