# Strange hiden state in OpenSSL 3.0.8 whcih changes behavior of PEM_read_bio_X509

Tags: c++, c, openssl, googletest

### Background

I have large C++ mutiplatform application, which uses static version of OpenSsl. Currently it uses OpenSsl in version `1.1.1t` and everything works.

Now I'm trying to do an upgrade to OpenSsl `3.0.8`. For that reason I need to use legacy provider otherwise my test are detecting some issues ([failing loading pfx file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76290230/1387438)). This fixes problems for multiple test I have.

### Problem

Now one of my tests is failing only when running all tests. When I run this tests only it is passing. Strange thing is that code under test is very simple and do not use any global states. This could explain this different behavior depending if other test are run or not. Only hidden global state of OpenSSL can explain this.

Code under test goes like this (almost exact copy paste):

```cpp
class FileCertsReader
{
public:
    ~FileCertsReader() = default;
    explicit FileCertsReader(boost::filesystem::path certificatesFile)
        : mFilePath{std::move(caCertificatesFile)}
    {
    }

    bool init()
    {
        mCertificates = utils::wrapUniqueThrow(BIO_new(BIO_s_file()));
        if (!mCertificates)
        {
            return false;
        }
    
        if (!BIO_read_filename(mCertificates.get(), mFilePath.string().c_str()))
        {
            mCertificates.reset();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    utils::UniquePtr<X509> enumerate()
    {
        return utils::wrapUnique(PEM_read_bio_X509(mCertificates.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr));
    }

private:
    boost::filesystem::path mFilePath;
    utils::UniquePtr<BIO> mCertificates;
};
```

Where `utils::wrapUnique` and `utils::UniquePtr<X509>` are just utilizing `std::unique_ptr` with respective custom deleter. This code is small and simple.

Now test is simple:

```cpp
TEST_F(FileCertsReaderTest, enumerate)
{
    auto store = std::make_unique<FileCertsReader>("single_file_ca_store.crt");
    ASSERT_TRUE(!!store);
    ASSERT_TRUE(store->init());

    ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(
        expectCertWithName(store->enumerate(), "CN=emSign Root CA - C1;O=eMudhra Inc;OU=emSign PKI;C=US"));

    ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(expectCertWithName(
        store->enumerate(), "CN=emSign Root CA - G1;O=eMudhra Technologies Limited;OU=emSign PKI;C=IN"));

    ASSERT_THAT(store->enumerate(), IsNull());

    auto sslError = ::ERR_get_error();
    
    char errString[512];
    ERR_error_string_n(sslError, errString, sizeof(errString));
    EXPECT_EQ(ERR_LIB_PEM, ERR_GET_LIB(sslError)) << errString;
    EXPECT_EQ(PEM_R_NO_START_LINE, ERR_GET_REASON(sslError)) << errString;
}
```

Now just to remind you:

- this test **always passes** when OpenSsl 1.1.1t is used, no mater if other test are run at the same time
- this **test passed** when using gtest_filter to run only this test
- this **test fails when all unit tests are run**. In such case I see in logs this:

```
...
[ RUN      ] FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate
/home/user/repo/project/Src/UnitTests/security/FileCertsReaderTest.cpp:155: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  9
  ERR_GET_LIB(err)
    Which is: 13
error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines::wrong tag

/home/user/repo/project/Src/UnitTests/security/FileCertsReaderTest.cpp:156: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  108
  ERR_GET_REASON(err)
    Which is: 168
error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines::wrong tag

[  FAILED  ] FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate (0 ms)
....
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1878 tests from 173 test suites ran. (24820 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1875 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate
```

As you can see reported error reported by OpenSSL is different when end of certificate list is reached.

When running only this test:

```
$ ./UnitTests --gtest_filter=FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate
Note: Google Test filter = FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from FileCertsReaderTest
[ RUN      ] FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate
[       OK ] FileCertsReaderTest.enumerate (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from FileCertsReaderTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

### Questions

- Is this know issue of OpenSSL? Is there way to address this issue?
- I have lots of tests (about 2k), is there a way to detect which test(s) has impact on this particular test? Can I ask `gtest` to run this problematic test between other test suites? This way I could fin which other test has impact on this failing test.

### Notes

- no other issues are detected. No leaks, UBs, all other tests are passing in all cases.
- here is my attempts to deliver MCRE on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/EdPz7hf1E https://godbolt.org/z/MaTY9q86Y but as I point out in question to have reproduction test I need to locate other test which impacts problematic test
- here is how openssl sees this certificate used for testing:

```bash
$ openssl x509 -in test/single_file_ca_store.crt -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ae:cf:00:ba:c4:cf:32:f8:43:b2
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, OU = emSign PKI, O = eMudhra Inc, CN = emSign Root CA - C1
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 18 18:30:00 2018 GMT
            Not After : Feb 18 18:30:00 2043 GMT
        Subject: C = US, OU = emSign PKI, O = eMudhra Inc, CN = emSign Root CA - C1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cf:eb:a9:b9:f1:99:05:cc:d8:28:21:4a:f3:73:
                    34:51:84:56:10:f5:a0:4f:2c:12:e3:fa:13:9a:27:
                    d0:cf:f9:79:1a:74:5f:1d:79:39:fc:5b:f8:70:8e:
                    e0:92:52:f7:e4:25:f9:54:83:d9:1d:d3:c8:5a:85:
                    3f:5e:c7:b6:07:ee:3e:c0:ce:9a:af:ac:56:42:2a:
                    39:25:70:d6:bf:b5:7b:36:ad:ac:f6:73:dc:cd:d7:
                    1d:8a:83:a5:fb:2b:90:15:37:6b:1c:26:47:dc:3b:
                    29:56:93:6a:b3:c1:6a:3a:9d:3d:f5:c1:97:38:58:
                    05:8b:1c:11:e3:e4:b4:b8:5d:85:1d:83:fe:78:5f:
                    0b:45:68:18:48:a5:46:73:34:3b:fe:0f:c8:76:bb:
                    c7:18:f3:05:d1:86:f3:85:ed:e7:b9:d9:32:ad:55:
                    88:ce:a6:b6:91:b0:4f:ac:7e:15:23:96:f6:3f:f0:
                    20:34:16:de:0a:c6:c4:04:45:79:7f:a7:fd:be:d2:
                    a9:a5:af:9c:c5:23:2a:f7:3c:21:6c:bd:af:8f:4e:
                    c5:3a:b2:f3:34:12:fc:df:80:1a:49:a4:d4:a9:95:
                    f7:9e:89:5e:a2:89:ac:94:cb:a8:68:9b:af:8a:65:
                    27:cd:89:ee:dd:8c:b5:6b:29:70:43:a0:69:0b:e4:
                    b9:0f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                FE:A1:E0:70:1E:2A:03:39:52:5A:42:BE:5C:91:85:7A:18:AA:4D:B5
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        c2:4a:56:fa:15:21:7b:28:a2:e9:e5:1d:fb:f8:2d:c4:39:96:
        41:4c:3b:27:2c:c4:6c:18:15:80:c6:ac:af:47:59:2f:26:0b:
        e3:36:b0:ef:3b:fe:43:97:49:32:99:12:15:5b:df:11:29:ff:
        ab:53:f8:bb:c1:78:0f:ac:9c:53:af:57:bd:68:8c:3d:69:33:
        f0:a3:a0:23:63:3b:64:67:22:44:ad:d5:71:cb:56:2a:78:92:
        a3:4f:12:31:36:36:e2:de:fe:00:c4:a3:60:0f:27:ad:a0:b0:
        8a:b5:36:7a:52:a1:bd:27:f4:20:27:62:e8:4d:94:24:13:e4:
        0a:04:e9:3c:ab:2e:c8:43:09:4a:c6:61:04:e5:49:34:7e:d3:
        c4:c8:f5:0f:c0:aa:e9:ba:54:5e:f3:63:2b:4f:4f:50:d4:fe:
        b9:7b:99:8c:3d:c0:2e:bc:02:2b:d3:c4:40:e4:8a:07:31:1e:
        9b:ce:26:99:13:fb:11:ea:9a:22:0c:11:19:c7:5e:1b:81:50:
        30:c8:96:12:6e:e7:cb:41:7f:91:3b:a2:47:b7:54:80:1b:dc:
        00:cc:9a:90:ea:c3:c3:50:06:62:0c:30:c0:15:48:a7:a8:59:
        7c:e1:ae:22:a2:e2:0a:7a:0f:fa:62:ab:52:4c:e1:f1:df:ca:
        be:83:0d:42
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Please don't tag this with "c" if it isn't C code. That said, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: How I can provide MCVE if failure happens only when I run all my tests? This test works perfectly if gtest application is run with filter to run single test.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt OpenSSL is a pure C interface, thus the *C++ code that uses C libraries (for example code using extern "C")* text from both the [C](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) tag descriptions applies

Comment: Can an OpenSSL 3.0.8-based `openssl` command-line utility read your X509 file?  For example:  `openssl x509 -in /path/to/x509.pem -text`  If not, check your PEM files for extraneous space characters in the body.

Comment: @AndrewHenle not the test. It reads 2 certificates with success, when trying reading 3 certificate which do not exist different error is reported then expected

Comment: @AndrewHenle note what the test do. It reads 2 certificates with success, when trying reading 3rd certificate, which do not exist, different error is reported then expected only when mutiple tests are run. Running only this one test it works. With opensSSL1.1.1t it works in all cases.

Comment: Dear colleagues looks like you are focused on wrong things. This test works, but fails in one scenario. To investigate issue I'm looking for way to find which other test (of those 1877) is impacting test I'm showing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've try provide best possible MCVE. It compiles, but I've filed to configure godbolt to run it properly. Also please note question is about interaction between tests so this test will just pass.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL behavior can be influenced by various factors including its initialization and configuration in different parts of a program.

Here is an example in C++ on how you can enforce the loading of the legacy provider explicitly in OpenSSL 3.0.8 which might help to stabilize the behavior:

```cpp
#include <openssl/provider.h>

bool load_legacy_provider() {
  OSSL_PROVIDER *legacy;
  legacy = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(nullptr, "legacy");
  if (legacy == nullptr) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// Call this function before any OpenSSL operations in your tests
// to ensure the legacy provider is loaded.
if (!load_legacy_provider()) {
  // Handle the error, the legacy provider could not be loaded.
}
```

Comment: In fact this is done. I've linked my other question in "Background" section where I had a problem with loading legacy provider. Provided answer (load legacy and default providers) fixed about 10 tests I had. Now I have problem only with this test which is now unstable (passes fails depending on circumstances). In fact in first version of this question I had this kind of code included, but I've removed it as noise to actual problem